# how to set schedule db2 automatic delete backup after 3 days from data studio

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I can successfully set backup of Data base but,
I want to Set Schedule from IBM Data studio for automatic delete database backup after few Days?

Answer (score 2):

The db cfg parameters that affect how backups is retained is:

```
NUM_DB_BACKUPS
REC_HIS_RETENTN
```

You can find a description of these at for example:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/kc_gen/plugin-root-config-gen2.html

I don't use datastudio myself, so perhaps there is a dedicated function in there, but I guess you can always use the ADMIN_CMD procedure. Here's an example on how to update db cfg:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023593.html